# Accessing Event Object from JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, stoppropagation, cancel-button

I have something similar to the following:

```
<div onclick="doSomething()">
   Content...
   <div onclick="doSomethingElse()">
   </div>
</div>
```

When `doSomethingElse()` is called, I don't want `doSomething()` to be called as well.

Searching the web, I found references to `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.cancelBubble()`, which prevent the event from *bubbling up* to parent elements.

Two questions:

1. How can I get the event object from `doSomethingElse()`?
2. Is it necessary to use both `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.cancelBubble()`, or has the industry settled on a standard for this?

Comment: You might consider using event delegation to simplify things: 
e.g., [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) You can just pass the event in as the first parameter of the function:

```
<div onclick="doSomething(event)">
   Content...
   <div onclick="doSomethingElse(event)">
   </div>
</div>

<script>
    function doSomethingElse(e) {
        // Prevent the doSomething event from being propagated after this one:
        e.stopPropagation();

        //OPTIONALLY: Prevent the *default* event from occurring:
        e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

(Note: the same works in jQuery event bindings)

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LheVL/3/)**

---

2.) I've started to see a lax in people using `cancelBubble` and instead switch over to `stopPropagation` entirely (the prior being used mostly for legacy IE support). Also, the MDN Docs say to use `stopPropagation` instead since **`cancelBubble` is both "non-standard" and "deprecated"** ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.cancelBubble)).

(Note: `stopPropagation` alone does not stop *default events*. For that, you'll want to call `event.preventDefault()` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)).

Comment: I had no idea I could just add `event` as a parameter like that. Where did it come from? I'll try it.

Comment: It's always passed through as the first parameter after an event is fired. Since it's JavaScript, you can completely ignore it as a parameter and all will be well lol.

Answer (score 0):

you should define `doSomethingElse' as follows:

```
var doSomethingElse = function(e){
    // e: event object ... so ...
    e.stopPropagation(); // enough
};
```

you should also pass the event object in your call: `doSomethingElse(event)`

event.stopPropagation() [works on all browsers, as for IE, works as expected on IE9 and later](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation).